# 'Could not parse level' Error While Loading CSV Data Into BigQuery Using BigQuery Transfer Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV into BigQuery from Cloud Storage using the BQ transfer service but I am getting the following error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'level' as INT64 for field word_count (position 1) starting at location 0 with message 'Unable to parse'
```

This doesn't make sense to me as the word_count column is clearly an integer:

[image]

I have checked the troubleshooting page in the documentation but no hint of what might be causing the issue.

What does it mean by 'level' and why could this be happening?

Comment: Try to make sure whether thr is no extra white space appended with values, which is causing an error.

Comment: Show the actual data (one row) that is causing this error. Your screenshot does not help.